# How to subscribe to each formGroup in a formArray

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, observable

I have a reactive form that has a formArray of at least 3 formGroups (and the possibility to have up to 20 total formGroups).  I want to know how/what is the most efficient way to subscribe to each formGroup in the formArray.  I know I can subscribe to the formArray and listen for changes on the children but I am looking to be able to subscribe to each individual formGroup in the formArray so I can do things like trigger something to happen on valueChange for one specific formGroup but leave the other formGroups alone that did NOT have any changes.

Currently the way I have it setup is I have a method to build a form and inside that form I do the subscribes there (of which I have 3 different subscribes happening).  This (while it works) seems like an unnecessarily large method and I feel like this method should only be for creating the formGroup and then I would think we would want to do the subscribing on NgOnInit (as from my understanding that is one of the better places to place subscriptions since on page load it will automatically start listening).

As you can see below I do 3 subscriptions: I look for valueChanges on the group as a whole and then specifically on one control in the the group along with looking for statusChange on the group as a whole as well.  I can't seem to find anything that talks about how I would accomplish this which I am surprised because I wouldn't think this would be a hyper specific scenario and other people would have info on how to accomplish this.

TS - Method that builds the form and holds all my subscriptions:

```
  buildRoundForm() : FormGroup {
    const roundFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      userRoundScore: [
        {
          value: null, disabled: true
        },
        {
        validators: [Validators.required, this.roundInputValidation(this.eighteenHoleRoundMin)],
        updateOn: 'change'
      }],
      courseRating: [67.5, [Validators.required]],
      slopeRating: [117, [Validators.required]],
      roundSelection: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });

    // used to dynamically set validation for user round input based on radio button selection
    roundFormGroup.controls.roundSelection.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.setValue(null)

      if (this.calcBtnDisabled === false) {
        this.calcBtnDisabled = true
      }

      if (value === 9 || value === 18) {
        roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.enable();
        roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.setValidators([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.min(value),
          this.roundInputValidation(value)
        ]);
      }
    
      roundFormGroup.controls.userRoundScore.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });
    })
  
    roundFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if(value && value.userRoundScore !== null && this.calcBtnDisabled) {
          this.calcBtnDisabled = false;
      }
    });
    
    // calculate score differential whenever status changes
    roundFormGroup.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
      this.calcScoreDifferential();
    });
    return roundFormGroup;
  }
```

HTML:

```
        <div formArrayName="roundInputsArray"
            *ngFor="let round of roundInputsArray.controls; let roundCount=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="roundCount">

                <!-- Round number -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label attr.for="{{'round_number' + roundCount}}">Round Number: </label>
                    <span id="{{'round_number' + roundCount}}"> {{roundCount+1}}</span>
                </div>

                <!-- 9 or 18 hole selection -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Round Selection: </label>
                    <div>
                        <label attr.for="{{'nineHoles' + roundCount}}">
                            <input type="radio"
                            id="{{'nineHoles' + roundCount}}"
                            [value]=9
                            formControlName="roundSelection">
                            9 Holes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label attr.for="{{'eighteenHoles' + roundCount}}">
                            <input type="radio"
                            id="{{'eighteenHoles' + roundCount}}"
                            [value]=18 
                            formControlName="roundSelection">
                            18 Holes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <!-- round score input -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label attr.for="{{'userRoundScore' + roundCount}}">Round Score: </label>
                    <input id="{{'userRoundScore' + roundCount}}" type="number" formControlName="userRoundScore" [min]="getMinScore(round.get('roundSelection')?.value)">
                    <br>
                    <span *ngIf="round.get('userRoundScore')?.errors?.['invalidForm']" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">Enter in a round of at least {{round.get('roundSelection')?.value === 18 ? '18' : '9'}}</span>
                </div>

                <!-- course rating input -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label attr.for="{{'courseRating' + roundCount}}">Course Rating: </label>
                    <input id="{{'courseRating' + roundCount}}" type="number" formControlName="courseRating">
                </div>

                <!-- slope rating input -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label attr.for="{{'slopeRating' + roundCount}}">Slope Rating: </label>
                    <input id="{{'slopeRating' + roundCount}}" type="number" formControlName="slopeRating">
                </div>

                <!-- Round Sum -->
                <div>
                    Score Differential: 
                    <span *ngFor="let total of roundTotal; let sumCount = index">
                        <span *ngIf="roundCount === sumCount">
                            {{total}}
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>

            </div>            
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-your-component',
      templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
    })
    export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      formArray: FormArray;
      formGroupSubscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.formArray = this.formBuilder.array([
          this.formBuilder.group({
            // your form controls for the first FormGroup
          }),
          this.formBuilder.group({
            // your form controls for the second FormGroup
          }),
          // Add more FormGroup instances as needed
        ]);
    
        // Subscribe to each FormGroup's valueChanges
        this.formArray.controls.forEach((formGroup: FormGroup) => {
          const subscription = formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
            // Do something with the changed value of the FormGroup
            console.log('Form group value changed:', value);
          });
          this.formGroupSubscriptions.push(subscription);
        });
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy() {
        // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions to prevent memory leaks
        this.formGroupSubscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.unsubscribe());
      }
    }
```

Comment: this works great but I am realizing now it's not going to work for me because I have a dynamica formArray so I am pushing and pulling items from the formArray.  If I loop through the array on ngOnInit and listen to each formGroup it's only listening to the groups on page load.  If I add a group it won't listen to that one.  I noticed if I listen to formArray and then on a change try and loop through the formArray and then make changes to a group I get an infinite loop and the program crashes

Answer (score 1):

You can use rxjs operators to make an unique subscription.

Imagine a function createSubscription

```
formArray!: FormArray;
subscription!: Subscription;

  createSubscription()
  {
    //we unsubscribe if yet is subcribe
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();

    //see how we "merge" the "valueChanges" observables
    //but we not only return the value else
    //return an object with the index of the array and the value using map

    this.subscription = merge(
      ...this.formArray.controls.map((x: AbstractControl, index: number) =>
        x.valueChanges.pipe(
          map((value: any) => ({
            index: index,
            value: value,
          }))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res); //res is an object in the way {index:#,value:...}
    });
  }
```

You can have a serie of auxiliar functions

```
  getGroup(index:number)
  {
    return this.formArray.at(index) as FormGroup
  }
  addGroup()
  {
    this.formArray.push(this.createGroup())
    this.createSubscription()
  }
  removeGroup(index:number)
  {
    this.formArray.removeAt(index)
    this.createSubscription()
  }
  createGroup(data: any = null) {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
```

Now you can use some like

```
<button (click)="addGroup()">Add</button>
<div
  *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls;let i=index"
  [formGroup]="getGroup(i)"
>
  <input formControlName="id" /><button (click)="removeGroup(i)">remove</button>
</div>
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-becgvk)

NOTE: subscribe to a valueChanges is not very common and generally it's not a good idea change validators. Better approach to your problem is create a custom validator and a directive to enable/disable a formControl

Answer (score 0):

To subscribe to each FormGroup in a FormArray in Angular, you can use the valueChanges or statusChanges observables provided by the AbstractControl class

Comment: that is correct I am aware of how to subscribe, my question is how to subscribe to each formGroup in the formArray and what is the most efficient way to do it?  Currently I have all my subscriptions in the method that builds a formGroup but I feel like that method should just be to create the formGroup and I should have the subscriptions in the ngOnInit and if that's the case how do I accomplish my question?  With my current implementation it works because when the formGroup is created it subscribes to the group or specific formControl

Comment: You can use the this.fb.group() inside the ngOnit() method above i have explain bit more as a new answer